# Gitlab docker upgrade to 14 hashed storage problems

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am facing some issues when updating Gitlab docker CE community edition to version 14

My actual version is gitlab-13.12.15-1 CE Community edition

my problem is that projects are not on hashed storage

```
Legacy storage is no longer supported. Please migrate your data to hashed storage.,

Check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/storage.html#migrate-to-hashed-storage for details.,
Upgrade failed. Retry the upgrade after migrating your data to hashed storage.,
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
```

On my actual installation all projects are not on hashed storage

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:storage:list_hashed_projects
* Found 0 projects using Hashed Storage
```

I followed ticket on gitlab support
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/upgrade-to-gitlab-13-4-0-b0481767fe4-killed-all-repositories/43038/24

```
sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole
-- Clear project tokens
UPDATE projects SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
-- Clear group tokens
UPDATE namespaces SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
-- Clear instance tokens
UPDATE application_settings SET runners_registration_token_encrypted = null;
-- Clear key used for JWT authentication
-- This may break the $CI_JWT_TOKEN job variable:
-- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/325965
UPDATE application_settings SET encrypted_ci_jwt_signing_key = null;
-- Clear runner tokens
UPDATE ci_runners SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
```

and also I did

```
-- Clear build tokens
UPDATE ci_builds SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
```

Then I used

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:storage:migrate_to_hashed
Enqueuing migration of 91 projects in batches of 200. Done!
```

I went to
select Menu > **Admin**.

Monitoring > **Background Jobs**.

But there isn't any running job..
[image]

any advice?

Comment: Me too stuck at this, pls help if you have solved this

Comment: still nothing from my side